# Spring Boot - no exception in DefaultErrorAttributes if URL not found?

Tags: java, exception, spring-boot

Do add custom attribute `errorCode` to my REST service I implemented a custom `ErrorAttributes` bean to override `getErrorAttributes`.

But my approach dosen't work for a 404 Not Found request, all attributes are set but `getError(requestAttributes)` returns NULL.

```
@Bean
public ErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
    return new DefaultErrorAttributes() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(
                RequestAttributes requestAttributes,
                boolean includeStackTrace) {
            Map<String, Object> errorAttributes = super.getErrorAttributes(requestAttributes, includeStackTrace);
            Throwable error = getError(requestAttributes);
            if (error instanceof AuthorizeException) {
                AuthorizeException authorizeException = (AuthorizeException) error;
                errorAttributes.put("errorCode", authorizeException.getErrorCode());
                errorAttributes.put("message", authorizeException.getMessage());
            } else if (error instanceof NotFoundException) {
                NotFoundException notFoundException = (NotFoundException) error;
                errorAttributes.put("errorCode", notFoundException.getErrorCode());
                errorAttributes.put("message", notFoundException.getMessage());
            } else if (error instanceof ServiceException) {
                ServiceException serviceException = (ServiceException) error;
                errorAttributes.put("errorCode", serviceException.getErrorCode());
                errorAttributes.put("message", serviceException.getMessage());
            } else {
                errorAttributes.put("errorCode", "9999");
                errorAttributes.put("message", error.getMessage());
            }
            return errorAttributes;
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to know what the problem might be. Do you have some code that's throwing a NotFoundException?

Comment: Each request to the service where no matching RequestMapping is define in a Controller.

Comment: A request where there's no matching request mapping doesn't throw a `NotFoundException` – there's no such class in Spring Framework or Spring Boot

Comment: The NotFoundException (my part) isn't the problem, I'm wondering why getError(requestAttributes) returns NULL in case of an unhandled request.

Comment: There's no exception thrown for an unhandled request so there's nothing for getError to return.